# Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 7340032, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 126651688)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I trained my model in Google colab and then saved it using `model1.save('thebestonesofar57block5.h5')`. After that I downloaded the file to my windows machine. After uploading it to a new google colab session, I'm getting the following error, using:

```
from keras.models import load_model

Loaded_model = load_model('thebestonesofar57block5.h5')
```

**Error:**

> OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 7340032,
>   sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 126651688)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon

Comment: Your downloaded .h5file is most likely corrupted perhaps due to an incomplete/erroneous download process.
Go back to the source and download the h5 file again.

Comment: I got the same error. It turns out that the model was not fully uploaded

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case somehow the .h5 file was corrupted or erroneous so I downloaded it again and voila it worked

Comment: Hi, Where did you download it from?

Comment: Train your model once and then after training, write this line of code

model.save_weights('file_name.h5')   

//model = your model name

Answer (score 4):

This happens either the weights file is corrupt or not downloaded properly.

Comment: this isnt an answer, should be a comment

Comment: same happened with me , I have downloaded the trained model and upload to the google colab. The model is not completely uploaded and I am trying to load in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
GG_Weights_path = keras.utils.get_file(
pretrained_url.split("/")[-1], pretrained_url)
print(VGG_Weights_path)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously because of a corrupted or partially downloaded .h5 file. I have faced a similar issue recently. To fix this issue you should have a complete .h5 file with you. Then follow the steps

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 4
> 5 model =tf.keras.models.load_model(r'E:\new_model')
> ----> 6 model_2 = VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), pooling='avg')
> 7
> 8 def crime_detection():
>
> E:\software\conda\envs\final\lib\site-packages\keras_vggface\vggface.py
> in VGGFace(include_top, model, weights, input_tensor, input_shape,
> pooling, classes)
> 92                 ' as true, `classes` should be 8631')
> 93
> ---> 94         return RESNET50(include_top=include_top, input_tensor=input_tensor,
> 95                         input_shape=input_shape, pooling=pooling,
> 96                         weights=weights,
>
> ```
> **E:\software\conda\envs\final\lib\site-packages\keras_vggface\vggface.py**
> ```
>
> in VGGFace(include_top, model, weights, input_tensor, input_shape,
> pooling, classes)
> 92                 ' as true, `classes` should be 8631')
> 93
> ---> 94         return RESNET50(include_top=include_top, input_tensor=input_tensor,
> 95                         input_shape=input_shape, pooling=pooling,
> 96                         weights=weights,

step:1 go to this python file **E:\software\conda\envs\final\lib\site-packages\keras_vggface\vggface.py**
you will find  [modules list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4oL0.jpg)

step2: open modules.py, you will find the function used to load weight. Use print to find where the .h5 model was downloaded by the program.
[finding path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbBg8.jpg) I have used printed the path using  **print(weights_path)**

step3: Once you get the location replace the old model with the new one that you have downloaded