# I'm receiving an error when using DeepFace.analyze in Pycharm. How should I solve it?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pycharm, artificial-intelligence, deepface

[This is the error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SxZT.png)

I tried to delete the deepface package and downloaded it again but it ends up displaying the same error. I'm a beginner at using Python too.

Comment: You should provide the source code as a snippet instead of file. Visit [Why shouldn't I upload images of code data errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The h5 file is corrupted or partially complete check [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606029/unable-to-open-file-truncated-file-eof-7340032-sblock-base-addr-0-store)